# How can I check given partial or incomplete python program is syntacticly correct or not

Tags: python, parsing, antlr4, abstract-syntax-tree

How can I write a program which can parse the incomplete and return True if the string of tokens till now can possibly generate syntactically correct python program and False if no syntactically correct python program can be generated ever.

Here is an example.

```
programs = ["def foo():", "def ():", "def foo(): return ", "def foo(x):\n  else"]

def check(program):
  '''
  returns True if program can be possibly completed as a valid python 
  program else False if there doesn't exist any string which can 
  be appended after the 'program' to make it valid python program.
  '''
  pass

print([check(program) for program in programs])
>> [True, False, True, False]
```

I know I can use antlr-python runtime which can check run the parser to check the grammar expansion rule in appropriate order, but I need pure python solution. Can I do this with only python ast module if not how can I do it with python-antlr-runtime.

Comment: Look into lex and yaac.

Comment: What did you find when you tried to do this with the `ast` module?

Comment: SyntaxError for all the cases, but I need to find such strings which can be prefix of valid python program.

Comment: Why should `check(programs[0])` be true? Also look into `ast.parse`. If there is a `SyntaxError`, that indicates the program is invalid.

Comment: I know that program[0] is invalid but it could be prefix for valid python program, which is not the case with program[1]. I want to classify between these two kinds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was managed to this antlr, here is my solution

```
from antlr4 import *
from antlr4.error import ErrorListener
from Python3Lexer import Python3Lexer
from Python3Parser import Python3Parser


class MyErrorListener(ErrorListener.ErrorListener):

  def syntaxError(self, recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, column, msg, e):
    if offendingSymbol.type == -1:
      pass
    else:
      raise Exception("syntaxError")

  def reportAmbiguity(self, recognizer, dfa, startIndex, stopIndex, exact, ambigAlts, configs):
    raise Exception("reportAmbiguity")

  def reportAttemptingFullContext(self, recognizer, dfa, startIndex, stopIndex, conflictingAlts, configs):
    raise Exception("reportAttemptingFullContext")

  def reportContextSensitivity(self, recognizer, dfa, startIndex, stopIndex, prediction, configs):
    raise Exception("reportContextSensitivity")


def check(program):

  try:
    input_stream = InputStream(program)
    lexer = Python3Lexer(input_stream)
    stream = CommonTokenStream(lexer)
    parser = Python3Parser(stream)
    parser.addErrorListener(MyErrorListener())

    parser.file_input()
    return True
  except Exception:
    return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
  programs = ["def foo():", "def ():", "def foo(): return ", "def foo(x):\n  else"]
  print([check(program) for program in programs])
```